# ssh chroot для пользователей с изолированным окружением

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, docker, chroot

Приветствую!
Пытаюсь настроить chroot для пользователей на centos 7. Перечитал кучу доков и пробовал все что есть.Пробовал через готовые [докер образы](https://github.com/Soletic/hosting-docker-ssh-chroot) сделать - не получается никак. никак не пойму как нормально сделать чрут с изолированным окружением.
Требования:

- Изолированное окружение со своим заране настроенным набором программ
- Возможность установить отдельному пользователю дополнительную программу ручками.
- Чрут полный. т.е. пользователь не должен гулять по системе и попытка перейти в корень, пошлет его в корень дом директории, а не в реальный корень системы.
- sftp

Я пробовал кучу всего, и там либо не работает совсем, либо как в случае с докер образом, окружение пользователя глючит: не правильно обрабатываются клавиши что ли, vim не корректно пишет и не реагирует на backspace, php-cli ничего не выводит в интерактивном режиме (echo "test"; ничего не выводит), mc с прозрачной темой и не реагирует на стрелки, но при этом реагирует на мышь и другие гор. клавиши.

Помогите плиз побороть недуг.

Comment: **окружение пользователя глючит: не правильно обрабатываются клавиши что ли** - а Вы учитываете, что при выполнении chroot меняется очень много чего. Например - каталог /etc, в котором хранятся настройки всех основных программ. И */home* будет другой. Соответственно, файл *.bashrc* тоже - совсем другой.

Comment: Дело в том, что админство не моя сильная сторона. Для этого я и затеял проект, что бы подтянуть знания. Я понимаю что я недолил окружение (вернее тот докер-скрипт не все копирует) но не знаю что именно. я копировал все каталоги что показал "whereis mc". Но этого мало, чую что то пропустил в конфигах консоли.

У меня директория /home совсем не настроена и пустая. там только .ssh. я понял что нужно настроить  .profile и .bash_profile. Подскажите плиз, на что еще нужно обратить внимание?

Comment: Добрый день. Вам нужно определится с задачей если окружение docker то тогда не нужно парится из-за chroot, docker это chroot своего рода просто накидайте Dockerfile свой, соберите его и можете делится им с теми кому нужно такое окружение. Если же нужен chroot тогда нужно конфигурировать 1 - ssh (/etc/ssh/sshd_config параметры Match Group, ChrootDirectory, AllowTCPForwarding, ForceCommand), 2 - окружение пользователя (useradd -M -s /bin/sh -U -d $chroot --groups $chrootgrp $user). А клавиши могут не правильно обрабатыватся из за шела который использует юзер проверить можно - echo $0